# Matlab: How to combine different matrices?

Tags: matlab, matrix

For example, I have 6 similar Matrices (Matrix A1 to A6) but with different data.

> Matrix A1:
>
> 2011/1/1 23.00 33.00 23.00 35.00 ...
>
> 2011/1/2 19.00 20.00 22.00 22.00 ... ...

I want to combine these 6 Matrices and create a new Matrix B.

The Matrix B will have: 6 columns and the length of the row equals (length(column of A)-1).

The first column of Matrix B is Matrix A1's first row (exclude date).

The second column of Matrix B is Matrix A2's first row (exclude date)...and so on...

I am looking for a script. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B = [A1(1,2:end); A2(1,2:end); A3(1,2:end); A4(1,2:end); A5(1,2:end); A6(1,2:end)]';
```

or

```
B = [A1(1,2:end)' A2(1,2:end)' A3(1,2:end)' A4(1,2:end)' A5(1,2:end)' A6(1,2:end)'];
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Instead of having multiple matrices with different names consider using cell array where each cell contains a matrix. If `A` is a cell array,

```
A = {A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6};
```

then you can access k-th matrix as `A{k}`. In this case you may have different number of matrices in the cell array and get B in a vectorized manner using, for example, this code:

```
B = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(1,2:end)', A, 'uniformoutput',0));
```

Comment: Thank you!! Just curious, if I want to shorten this code, how could I do? separate it into different lines or a loop? What the script would be?

Comment: If you want to stick with your variable names, you can use EVAL in a for-loop, but it's considered a bad practice. Using cell array is preferred.